# Oracle Debezium connector skips some logs

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

We have an oracle debezium source connector which seems to run fine. But recently we realized some of the contents of table are not transferred to kafka topic. This is the connector:

```
"connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector",
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
"tombstones.on.delete": "false",
"schema.include.list": "SPIKEVPO",
"table.include.list": "SPIKEVPO.COR_OUTBOX",
"column.exclude.list": "SPIKEVPO.COR_OUTBOX.PAYLOAD",
"database.user": "${file:/kafka/vty/pass.properties:vpo_user}",
"database.password": "${file:/kafka/vty/pass.properties:vpo_pwd}",
"database.connection.adapter": "logminer",
"database.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=HOST_NAME)(PORT=1234))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DB_NAME)))",
"database.server.name": "VPO_REVERSALTRANSACTION",
"database.dbname": "DB_NAME",
"database.history.kafka.topic": "VPO_REVERSALTRANSACTION_hist",
"database.history.consumer.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
"database.history.consumer.sasl.jaas.config": "${file:/kafka/vty/pass.properties:sasl}",
"database.history.consumer.security.protocol": "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
"database.history.producer.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
"database.history.producer.sasl.jaas.config": "${file:/kafka/vty/pass.properties:sasl}",
"database.history.producer.security.protocol": "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
"database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "http://anstdkaflx11.vakifbank.intra:9082",
"transforms": "outbox",
"transforms.outbox.type": "io.debezium.transforms.outbox.EventRouter",
"transforms.outbox.route.topic.replacement": "${routedByValue}",
"transforms.outbox.table.field.event.payload": "PAYLOADID",
"transforms.outbox.table.fields.additional.placement": "ID:envelope,AGGREGATETYPE:envelope,AGGREGATEID:envelope,TYPE:envelope:type,RECORDDATE:envelope,EVENTNAME:envelope",
"key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
"database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl": "true",
"acks": "1",
"max.queue.size": "81290",
"max.batch.size": "20480",
"poll.interval.ms": "2000",
"log.mining.strategy": "online_catalog",
"heartbeat.interval.ms": "60000",
"snapshot.mode": "schema_only"
```

There is no ERROR or WARN log in connector logs. Only this SCN gap appears, as an INFO:

```
 The connector is now using the maximum batch size 100000 when querying the LogMiner view. This could be indicative of large SCN gaps
```

In the oracle side, there is no sign of debezium outage. Logminer looks ok for the given time interval that the problem occured

```
LOGMINER: HighConsumedScn: 0
LOGMINER: PSR flags: 0x0
LOGMINER: Session Flags: 0x4000441
LOGMINER: Session Flags2: 0x0
LOGMINER: Read buffers: 4
LOGMINER: Region Queue size: 256
LOGMINER: Redo Queue size: 4096
LOGMINER: Memory Size = 15M, HWM 14M, LWM 13M, 90%
LOGMINER: Memory Release Limit: 0M
LOGMINER: Max Decomp Region Memory: 1M
LOGMINER: Transaction Queue Size: 1024
LOGMINER: summary for session# = 2149952513, OS id=63146
LOGMINER: StartScn: 9271776919506 (0x0000086ec0f83fd2)
LOGMINER: EndScn: 9271778078284 (0x0000086ec109ee4c)
```

We see the records on table, debezium works, connector works, but for a limited time those records are not transferred to topic. What may be the reason? Thanks in advance.